# Reference request - Theory of rational multivariate generating functions (extracting coefficients of their taylor expansion)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

I'm looking for a book/text/paper/etc. that develops the theory of multivariate (/bivariate) generating functions with special focus on how to extract coefficients.

If possible, I'd like the source to develop a theorem that allows one to directly transform the rational generating function into the underlying coefficient-sequence.

In the case of univariate generating functions this theory looks roughly like this: 
Given a rational generating function $F(x)= \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$  of $ \sum_{n\ge 0}a_n x^n$ determine the reciprocals of the zeroes of $Q(x)$ with their multiplicity.

This then gives us the function class of $a_n$. We substitute in the first few values and solve the equation system for the unknowns, and arrive at a formula for $a_n$.

Can anybody hint me to good references for this theory?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd be interested in the text [Asymptotic Combinatorics in Several Variables](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/ACSV.pdf)  by Robin Pemantle and Mark Wilson, as well as their article [Twenty Combinatorial Examples of Asymptotics Derived from Multivariable Generating Functions](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/twenty.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for these links! I wasn't aware that there was so much work in this area.

Answer (score 1):

After some more researching, it turns out that it's doubtful that such a theory exists, at least not in a calculus using only elementary functions:

Even rather simple bivariate generating functions like
$$F(x,y) = \frac{x·(x - 2)}{(x - 1)^2·(x + y - 2)}$$
seem to develop into taylor-series with coefficients that have no closed formula.

(The upper generating function develops into the taylor-series:

$$
\sum_{n,k\ge 0} \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n(i + 2)·\binom{n - i + k}{ n - i}\cdot \frac 1{2^{n - i + k - 3}}}{16} x ^{n+1} y^k
$$
The coefficients have a known closed form involving the hypergeometric sum, but none only using elementary functions (at least as far as I could deduce)

There are however instances that admit closed formulas for the coefficients of the taylor-series, with many special cases coming from lattice-theory.

While not necessarily achieving a closed formula, a method that at least always allows one to develop a rational generating function into a taylor-series is the following:

Let $ F(x_1,..,x_n) = P(x_1,..,x_n)/Q(x_1,..,x_n) := P/Q$.

- Factorize Q into factors $Q_1\dots Q_k$ so that for each factor $Q_i$ you can develop the taylor-series of $1/Q_i$ (at worst you'll have to split $Q$ into is linear factors, which all admit a simple taylor-series)..
- We now have $F = 1/Q_1 \cdots 1/Q_k$. We then develop each factor into its taylor-series.
- Finally, we convolute the taylor-series and try to simplify the resulting expression.

Even for multivariate generating functions however there are special classes that always admit a closed formula. 
One for example is when a rational generating function $F(x_1,..,x_n)$ is seperable into $F(x_1,..,x_n) = F_1(x_1) \cdots F_n(x_n)$.

In this case the denominator of $F(x_1,..,x_n)$ admits a factorization of linear factors which each have only a single variable. We can then group all linear factors which the same variable together, and apply the method from above, which in this case always gives a closed formula.

Answer (score 1):

There's some relevant material in Chapter 6 of Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume 2* (particularly, [extracting the diagonal](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/extracting-the-diagonal/) $\sum f(n, n) x^n$ of a bivariate rational generating function $\sum f(n, m) x^n y^m$), and some more in Chapter IX of Flajolet and Sedgewick's *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* (which is mostly about getting asymptotics).

Comment: I just skimmed the paper linked in Rus May's answer and the method there is much more comprehensive than any material in Stanley or Flajolet-Sedgewick (which is a shock to me!), although it requires more background to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem: "given a rational function $f \in Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and a monomial $M$, find the coefficient of $M$ in $f$" is NP-hard.  That implies that probably you can't go further than some occasionally successful heuristics.